# Perform cardinality-Many in JOLT

Tags: arrays, json, mapping, transformation, jolt

I want to write a Jolt definition using **`cardinality`** - **`MANY`** that can transform object "**PO_POD_LN_EVW1**" into list and ignore if its already a list.

**Input JSON :**

```json
{
  "PURCHASE_ORDER_DISPATCH": {
    "MsgData": {
      "Transaction": {
        "PSCAMA": {
          "PUBLISH_RULE_ID": {
            "IsChanged": "Y"
          }
        },
        "PO_POD_HDR_EVW1": {
          "STATE_BILL": "",
          "CURRENCY_CD": {
            "IsChanged": "Y",
            "content": "USD"
          },
          "ADDRESS4_VNDR": "",
          "PO_POD_LN_EVW1": {
            "WG_ACCOUNT": 641100,
            "LINE_NBR": {
              "IsChanged": "Y",
              "content": 1
            },
            "ITM_ID_VNDR": "B0798CX2Q9",
            "PO_POD_SHP_EVW1": {
              "LINE_NBR": {
                "IsChanged": "Y",
                "content": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "WG_ADDR_SEQ_NUM": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**JOLT Spec :**

```json
{
  "operation": "cardinality",
  "spec": {
    "PURCHASE_ORDER_DISPATCH": {
      "MsgData": {
        "Transaction": {
          "PO_POD_HDR_EVW1": "MANY"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Getting this error: **Failed to Transform**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jolt spec is correct, But You should wrap all of your specs in the `[]` array.

Try this:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "PURCHASE_ORDER_DISPATCH": {
        "MsgData": {
          "Transaction": {
            "PO_POD_HDR_EVW1": "MANY"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```